# Стилизованныe radio button. Как обработать клик по span, чтобы передать checked input?

Tags: javascript, html, radiobutton

Скрыл стандартное отображение группы радиокнопок и заменил из стилизованными span. Нужно средствами JS обработать клик по span и изменить состояние input находящееся с ним в родительском div в состояние checked. И добавить span псевдоэлемент before который будет выглядеть как закрашенная точка чтобы визуально отобразить какая радиокнопка выбрана.

```
<form action="script.php">
        <div class="form-group_2">
            <input type="radio" id="input_3" name="category" value="one"
                   class="real-radio" checked="true">
            <span class="custom-radio_1"></span>
            <label for="input_3" id="prom_1">Плоские буквы</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group_2">
            <input type="radio" id="input_4" name="category" value="two"
                   class="real-radio">
            <span class="custom-radio_1"></span>
            <label for="input_4" id="prom_2">Плоские с контражурной подсветкой</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group_2">
            <input type="radio" id="input_5" name="category" value="three"
                   class="real-radio">
            <span class="custom-radio_1"></span>
            <label for="input_5" id="prom_3">Объемные без подсветки</label>
        </div>
</form>
```

Вот js файл

```
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-radio_1');
      spans.forEach(span=>{
      span.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        span.classList.toggle('check');
        span.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('checked', 'true');
    })})
```

В общем скрипт получает nodelist из спанов. После перебирает его и вешает на каждый обработчик события клик. При клике вызывается функция которая получает соседний элемент - то есть нужный инпут и меняет его свойство checked. А также добавляет спану класс css который добавит псевдоэлемент который будет выглядеть как точка в центре радиокнопки. Проблема в том, что свойство чекед должно добавляться только последней выбранной кнопке и удалятся у всех остальных как в стандартном браузерном API.То же самое касается и добавляемому классу check который должен добавлять точку внутри только последней выбранной радиокнопки и удалять у всех предыдущих кнопок. Хотелось бы решение на чистом JS без jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прям так сильно хочется оставить span и использовать JS для переключения, то вот:

```
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-radio_1');
  spans.forEach(span=>{
  span.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    spans.forEach(sp => {
      if(sp !== span){
        sp.classList.remove('check');
        sp.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('checked', 'false');
      }  
    })
    span.classList.toggle('check');
    span.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('checked', 'true');
})})
```

Comment: Отличное решение. Именно это и было нужно

Answer (score 1):

Зачем же использовать `span`, если есть `label`, которому можно задать `for="input_1"` (id input-а) и клик по нему будет включать/отключать в том числе и скрытый `radio`